# use indexof() to find inconsistent value of a path

Tags: javascript

```
www.google.com/page/2
```

it's easy if the path is like above, we can use

```
path.substring(10, path.length);
```

but what if the url is like this

```
www.google.com/page/2
www.google.com/page/233
www.google.com/page/2/more/here/
```

how can I get the page number? I mean the 2.

Comment: www.google.com/page/233 would mean page number is 233..?

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Comment: "inconsistent value of a path" --- what does it mean?

Comment: split on `'/'` and access the items of the array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using regex

```
str = 'www.google.com/page/2/userId/433'; // (you can put any page number you want instead of 2)

pageNumber = str.split('/')[2];
alert(pageNumber);
```

It will cut the string into an array for each '/' there is, and with `[2]` we get the second part, which is everything after 'page/' but before the next '/'.

As far as it goes for the moment, I think my solution is the best because if your URL becomes 'www.google.com/page/2/index/3', all the regex posted previously are printing either 3, or 2 and 3, while mine will always print the page Id.
But im sure it is possible to make a good regex that will do the job, too.

Comment: Your last statement isn't fully correct. My answer will always yield the right answer if you access it with `whateverVariableName[0]`. Other than that yours is another clean and short solution.

Comment: True, you should maybe update it then, because it may stop to work if OP ever has an address like that!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). For Javascript that's [String.match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp).

You can use it like this:

```
"www.google.com/page/233/more/here?userid=913".match(/\d+/g);
// returns an array with every match:
["233","913"]

// In case you directly want your answer, you can just append the index:
"www.google.com/page/233/more/here?userid=913".match(/\d+/g)[0];
"233"
```

The two wrapping `/` are delimiters of the expression, `\d` selects every digit and the `+` means, that it will match every occurence, that's bigger than one (so it'll match `1`, `233`, `2512`, but no empty strings). Finally the `g` in the end is a modifier that will do a [*global* search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) - But it's not necessarily needed as you only need the first occurence anyways.

Comment: oh wait, what if it contain not only the page number, like page/233/post=99, will this regex work?

Comment: @user3836151: what should it select in that case?

Comment: If you know, that the number will always be the first result, it will. `.match()` returns an array of all matches, so in your case it will return `["233", "99"]`. You will always need to access it with its index (`match[0]` for instance).

Comment: @Padarom: actually it will not. You need to put `/g` to match everything

Comment: then I have to write more logic? if there is only 233 then I write match[0] then it will be null, am I correct?

Comment: @user3836151 No, `match[0]` (of course you have to assign the returned value to this variable) will always contain the first occurence of a number in the string. So in your example `match` would be `["233","99"]`. You can get the _233_ with `match[0]` and the _99_ with `match[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a little regex:

```
var url = 'www.google.com/page/2/more/here/'

var match = url.match(/^.+\/.+\/([0-9]+)/);

alert(match[1]);
```

Exciting fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimdotdotdot/f2qot2q3/

Comment: What happens if url becomes 'www.google.com/page/2/more/userId/113' ?

Comment: @Enjoyted According to my browser's Javascript console the array will contain `["www.google.com/page/2/more/userId/113", "113"]`, so actually it's wrong when looking for the page.

Comment: @Padarom Yes I knew, it was kind of a rhetorical question :P

Answer (score -1):

```
var parts = path.split('/');
for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
   if(parts[i] == 'page'){
      alert(parts[i+1]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like javascript to me, just missing a ")", `if(parts[i] == ('page')){`

Comment: it was java before..my mistake :-)

Comment: For brevity, you can omit the parantheses, `if(parts[i] == 'page')`. It's also a good idea to use `var` to avoid polluting the global scope, `var parts`, `var i`